# comparing dates to make sure they are withing 7 days of eachother in python

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison

I am trying to see if a date is equal to another date but the second date can be plus or minus 7 days how can I do this?

This is the structure of the code I already have, I just dont know how to finish.

```
 for value, date in zip(asIsValueRow.split()[3:], dateRow.split()[1:]):

            if value == varianceTwo and date == priorProdDate:
```

Oh and I'm also checking to see if the value is exactly the same as another value I only need the date to be within 7 days.
and the structure of the dates are:     01/10/2017

Comment: Python timedelta objects will probably be useful. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like priorDate.min(7) <= date or date <= priorDate.max(7) but there seems to be no way of doing this. I looked at the timedate module, but nothing seemed to apply to this case.I don't know what kind of function to use. I could compare just days but that doesn't work if its from last month. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `timedelta` as fredriksapps suggests

```
if priorProdDate - timedelta(days=7) <= date <= priorProdDate + timedelta(days=7):
    # do something with data
```

Comment: Worked like a Charm Thank you